# print to a text file in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

```
const fs = require('fs');

const content = 'Some content!'

fs.writeFile('C:/Users/Shreyas Joshi/Desktop/file.txt', content, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return
  }
})
```

Is this the right way? if not please tell the right way to do it. Thank you

Comment: are you expecting a solution like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-z6spav ? or you need solution in node ?

Comment: ReactJS is UI library. It doesnt handle writing to files/calling APIs/Inserting it to DB. We should use some external module to do so. And even in your case, you should some external module to do so.